Push Notifications Not Received on iOS Devices in BrowserStack with Appium and C#
I'm currently running automation tests on BrowserStack using Appium and C#. I've encountered an issue specifically with the iOS version.
Push notifications appear on physical devices, but they are not visible on the device in the Browser Stack.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The details that you have provided are insufficient to find out the root cause of the issue, however to answer your query, support for Push Notifications is enabled on BrowserStack devices for you to be able to test the Push Notification scenarios in your app.
For Push Notifications to work on iOS devices, you will need to build your app using an enterprise-signed certificate as Push Notifications will not work for developer-signed apps. So, you can validate the same once from your end.
